# JavaScript: Dynamic Script Loading without manipulating the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-script-loading

How do I **add an external JavaScript**(-library) to a page through JavaScript-code without:

- Manipulating the DOM
- *Preferably* without using `Eval`?

That means adding a `script`-tag through JavaScript is not allowed.

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) tells me "Eval is Evil", so **I'm looking to see if there is an option**. One that would pass JSLint.

**Please avoid answers using frameworks**, but looking into how jQuery, ExtJS, Require.js and the likes solve dynamic script loading would be interesting.

Comment: Any reason that you want to load an arbitrary file without eval or `<script>` tags?

Comment: Because the environment I'm working on right now doesn't allow script-tags and eval is evil. Will that information change your answer?

Comment: `eval` is a tool, but almost never the right one for the job. *Eval is Evil* is a generalisation. It sounds like you may have a weird edge case where it is the only tool for the job. (Either that or the right tool is a sledgehammer applied to possible artificial limits you are working within).

Comment: If eval is what you need to do, then eval is the right tool for the job.  However, judging by your sample, it just looks like you need script/@src.

Comment: Down-votes for exploring an option? The "just use jQuery anyways!"-culture here really shines through.

Comment: @SebNilsson no idea why people are downvoting ... but you are the first person on this question to use the word "jQuery" ....

Comment: @ManseUK It's a reference to the SO-podcast where they discussed a problem in the mentality where people ask "How do I do X in JS, but I can't use jQuery" and people just spam with "Just use jQuery anyways!". Sometimes the environment doesn't allow everything.

Comment: @SebNilsson: What exactly do you have against `eval`?  Is it that you have heard people say that it is evil, or that it is explicitly banned in your environment?  If the latter, then any workaround is likely to be banned for the same reason.  If the former, then use it if you have to.  Whichever it is, you still need to give strong consideration as to whether you really need it.

Comment: @PaulButcher Hearsay and that JSLint insults my code. Just looking if there are any alternatives! Jeez...

Comment: `eval` is not evil just because it has the letters e,v & l in it; but because of what it can allow.  Whatever technique you use to do "evals" without `eval` will be just as evil, if not more so because the eval will be obfuscated, than overtly using eval.

Comment: @PaulButcher Then post that in a constructive answer and it'll probably be the correct answer.

Comment: Do *not* repost this.  Fix it, or bounty it.

Answer (score 1):

Except by using something like `new Function(String);` (which is effectively `eval` by proxy and thus not an option in any circumstance where `eval` is ruled out due to being evil), you can't.

Comment: @RobW — No, with a string extracted from a file and then manipulated.

Comment: it still is an implicit `eval`

Comment: @jAndy — Yes, I said that (and because it is an implicit `eval` I didn't bother trying to figure out the details of the string manipulation).

Comment: +1 for at least giving creativity a try, even if staying with `eval` seems like a better option than this :P

Answer (score 1):

I seriously see no reason behind your intention. Your question is about "dynamic script loading", there is no "`eval is evil`" speech for that reason.

You're clearly going to load and execute ECMAscript code, that is a very valid point for using `eval`. Since this is your declared goal (executing javascript code), what is your exact problem in using `eval` ? Regardless how you execute that code, it might always be dangerous or malicous. There is no "`.evalButBeCareful()`" method available (yet).

So my best guess is, that you kind of want to load some piece of code without letting the user know about that. Fortunately, this is impossible. It might be possible to hide code from a novice, but if somebody wants to he always can easily see whats loaded onto the current site.

Comment: The intention is simply to learn more about JavaScript and script loading. If the answer is `eval` then so be it. Knowledge found...